# Weird NULL situation in Laravel Eloquent models

Tags: php, laravel, model, null, eloquent

I am facing a really weird problem using Laravel.

I have 4 tables (there are more, but they have nothing to do with the problem):

```
platoons
- id
- game_id
- leader_id
- name

games
- id
- name
- icon

game_user_info_fields
- id
- game_id
- user_info_id

user_info_fields
- id
- name
```

**Models of these tables contain the following relation methods:**

```
class Platoon extends \Eloquent {
    public function game() {
        return $this->belongsTo('Game');
    }
}

class Game extends \Eloquent {
    protected $fillable = [];
    protected $table = 'games';

    public function fields() {
        return $this->hasMany('GameUserInfoField');
    }
}

class GameUserInfoField extends \Eloquent {
  protected $fillable = [];
  protected $table = 'game_user_info_fields';

  public function field() {
    return $this->belongsTo('UserInfoField');
  }

  public function game() {
    return $this->belongsTo('Game');
  }
}

class UserInfoField extends \Eloquent {
  protected $fillable = [];
  protected $table = 'user_info_fields';

  public function fields() {
    return $this->hasOne('GameUserInfoField');
  }
}
```

**Table data:**

```
platoons
id game_id leader_id name
1  1       1         Battlefield 4 
2  2       1         CS:GO
3  3       1         LoL
4  4       1         GTAV

games
id  name               icon
1   Battlefield 4      bf4.png
2   CS:GO              csgo.png
3   League of Legends  lol.png
4   GTA V              gtav.png

game_user_info_fields
id  game_id  user_info_field_id
1   1        1
2   1        2
3   2        3
4   3        4
5   4        5

user_info_fields
id  name
1   Origin username
2   Battlelog link
3   Steam ID
4   LoL username
5   Social club username
```

**The problem:**

(the **HLP::pp()** method is a helper, similar to the function **dd()**)

```
$platoon = Platoon::where('id', '=', Input::get('platoon_id'))->first();

foreach ($platoon->game->fields as $gameuserinfofield) {
    HLP::pp($gameuserinfofield->field);
}
```

Returns **NULL**, when it should return the **UserInfoField** model, while

```
foreach ($platoon->game->fields as $gameuserinfofield) {
    HLP::pp($gameuserinfofield->game);
}
```

returns the Game model, as it should.

They both have the same kind of relationship, just different tables, so I don't get how it couldn't retrieve the model...

Retrieving the model straight through

```
UserInfoField::all();
```

does retrieve the model, as it should.

I've been stuck on this for the last 4 hours and couldn't fix it, please, help!

Comment: Try passing the foreign key column name like this: `return $this->belongsTo('Game', 'user_info_field_id');`

Comment: tried that before, and just did again, and it doesn't help

Comment: Take a look at the return value of `$gameuserinfofield->field()->toSql()`

Comment: Wait I think you specified your relationships a bit wrong. As I see it `Game` has a many to many relationship with `UserInfoField`. That means you can use `$this->belongsToMany('Game')` and `$this->belongsToMany('UserInfoField')`. Make sure to check out the docs on the topic if you don't understand what I'm talking about...

Comment: Great. I'm going to write a little answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overcomplicating things with your relationship. You can simply specify them as what it is. A many to many relation. This is done using `belongsToMany()`:

```
public function fields(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('UserInfoField');
}
```

This new relation makes the `GameUserInfoField` model completely obsolete.